# Is there any way to open the model performance graphs of TensorBoard, in Python or R?

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, tensorboard, loss-function

[image: This is the loss graph generate in TensorBoard]

I need to open this TensorBoard graph in Python or R.

Answer (score 2):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_scalar_run_tensorboard(tag, filepath):
    values,steps = [],[]
    for e in tf.compat.v1.train.summary_iterator(filepath):
        if len(e.summary.value)>0: #Skip first empty element
            if e.summary.value[0].tag==tag:
                tensor = (e.summary.value[0].tensor)
                value,step = (tf.io.decode_raw(tensor.tensor_content,tf.float32)[0].numpy(),e.step)
                values.append(value)
                steps.append(step)
    return values,steps
```

e.g.

```
val,st = get_scalar_run_tensorboard("epoch_loss",
                               "./logs/your_log/your_run/train/your_file.v2")

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(st,val)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use [summary_iterator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/train/summary_iterator) to read the event file generated by Tensorflow and [make_ndarray](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/make_ndarray) to extract the tensor values from it.

*Setup*

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

TAG_NAME = "classification_loss"

writer_train = tf.summary.create_file_writer("train")

for epoch in range(200):
    data = np.math.exp(-(epoch/30)) + 0.1*np.random.random()
    with writer_train.as_default():
        tf.summary.scalar(name=TAG_NAME, data=data, step=epoch)

# output folder: train/events.out.tfevents.1618103384.eafddbceac44.283.2075165.v2
```

*Read event file*

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

TAG_NAME = "classification_loss"
tf_event_file = "train/events.out.tfevents.1618103384.eafddbceac44.283.2075165.v2"

value_list = []
for e in tf.compat.v1.train.summary_iterator(tf_event_file):
    for v in e.summary.value:
        if v.tag == TAG_NAME:
            value = tf.make_ndarray(v.tensor)
            value_list.append(value)

plt.plot(value_list)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: tensorboard_and_matplotlib]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the best and easiest way is you can download the graph data in CSV or JSON format from Tensorboard. Once you have graph data you can import data and plot it.