# Download all of csv files of tensorboard at once

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorboard

I wanted to download the data of all my runs at once in tensorboard:
[image]

But it seems there's not a way to download all of them in one click. Does anyone know any solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with this to solve my problem. First, you'll need to run the TensorBoard on a local host and then scrape the data from the browser.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from csv import reader
import os


def URLs(fold, trial):
    URLs_dict = {
    'train_accuracy' : f'http://localhost:6006/data/plugin/scalars/scalars?tag=epoch_accuracy&run=fold{fold}%5C{trial}%5Cexecution0%5Ctrain&format=csv',
    'val_accuracy' : f'http://localhost:6006/data/plugin/scalars/scalars?tag=epoch_accuracy&run=fold{fold}%5C{trial}%5Cexecution0%5Cvalidation&format=csv',
    'val_loss' : f'http://localhost:6006/data/plugin/scalars/scalars?tag=epoch_loss&run=fold{fold}%5C{trial}%5Cexecution0%5Cvalidation&format=csv',
    'train_loss' : f'http://localhost:6006/data/plugin/scalars/scalars?tag=epoch_loss&run=fold{fold}%5C{trial}%5Cexecution0%5Ctrain&format=csv'
    }
    return URLs_dict

def tb_data(log_dir, mode, fold, num_trials):
    trials = os.listdir(log_dir)
    fdf = {}
    for i, trial in enumerate(trials[:num_trials]):
        r = requests.get(URLs(fold, trial)[mode], allow_redirects=True)
        data = r.text
        data_csv = reader(data.splitlines())
        data_csv = list(data_csv)
        df = pd.DataFrame(data_csv)
        headers = df.iloc[0]
        df  = pd.DataFrame(df.values[1:], columns=headers)
        if i == 0:
            fdf['Step'] = df['Step']  
        fdf[f'trial {trial}'] = df['Value']
    fdf = pd.DataFrame(fdf)
    return fdf
```

P.S: It might need a little tweaking based on a different directory.

Answer (score 1):

This can lead to your answer!

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73409436/11657898

that's for 1 file, but, it's ready to put into a loop

Comment: Upvote for relevance; however, I'm unsure if it answers my question. I've added my solution, which works for me.

Comment: Thanks, and, of course, my answer leak of the recursively search for every file in every folder for your project